# UnimplementedError error in FutureBuilder while displaying inserted data from database

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm trying to create a Futurebuilder function to call and display all data that inserted in database unfortunately I got this error 'UnimplementedError' and im pretty stock on this any suggestion will be appreciated.

Here in my full code for implementation to display data in been trying to fix my error 'UnimplementedError' in which I'm trying to do is to display inserted in list view not in web view any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
body: Center(
  child: Expanded(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder<ContactsDao>(
              future: _calltheStream(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<ContactsDao> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData ||
                    snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
                  return Container(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                } else {
                  return StreamBuilder<List<ContactObject>>(
                      stream: snapshot.data.findallContactsById(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData ||
                            snapshot.connectionState ==
                                ConnectionState.none) {
                          return Container(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        } else {
                          if(widget.Contactlist.length != snapshot.data.length){
                            widget.Contactlist = snapshot.data;
                          }

                          if(snapshot.data.length == 0){
                            return Center(
                              child: Text('No Data Found'),
                            );
                          }
                          return Expanded(
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                itemBuilder:
                                    (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return Card(
                                      child: ListTile(
                                        leading: Checkbox(
                                          value: widget.Contactlist[index].isSelect,
                                          onChanged: (bool value) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              widget.Contactlist[index].isSelect = value;
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ),
                                        trailing: GestureDetector(
                                          onTap: () {
                                            _selectedDetele(snapshot.data[index].id);
                                          },
                                          child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                        ),
                                         title: Text('${snapshot.data[index].task}',maxLines: 1,),
                                         subtitle: Text('${snapshot.data[index].time}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),),
                                      ));
                                }),
                          );
                        }
                      }); //DATA
                } //DATA
              }), // DATA
        ], // DATA
      ), // DATA
  ),//DATA
),

Future<ContactsDao> _calltheStream() async { //GET ALL DATA HERE
  ContactDatabase contactDatabase =  await widget.database;
  widget._contactsdao = contactDatabase.contactsDao;
  return contactDatabase.contactsDao;
}
```

Comment: `UnimplementedError` normally means that you have forgotten to implement a method in a class you have extended/implemented (in which case it will contain `throw UnimplementedError`) or you are using a plugin that isn't fully compatible with the platform you are on, which frequently happens with Flutter web. Please add more details, including the implementation of `_callTheStream()`

Comment: Hi sir plesae see the code with my implementation of  _callTheStream() Thank you.

Comment: Nothing in that code will throw `UnimplementedError` directly, so it must be something in the functions/getters you call, so probably something in your class `ContactDatabase`. Have you defined the getter `ContactDatabase.contactsDao`? Are you using any specific plugin? Is this plugin compatible with the platform you are using?

Comment: ohh i see , im using floor database plugin sir.

Comment: really appreciated sir Thank you

Comment: what is the full error?

Comment: the error is just 'UnimplementedError' got some missing parameters in floor database Thanks for asking